Rendering and sending data to EJS template
I am a newbie NodeJS developer and I am trying to fetch data from MongoDB and render it to another .ejs file to display it. But error showing that data is not defined in the line <% data.forEach(post => { %>
main.js:
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Post = require('../models/posts');


router.get('', async (req, res) => {

    const locals = {
        title: 'Blog Post',
        description: "A blog website created using Node.js, Express, and MongoDB."
    }
    
    try {
        const data = await Post.find();
        res.render('index', { locals, data });
    } 
    catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
});

module.exports = router;

index.ejs:
<ul class="article-ul">

    <% data.forEach(post => { %>
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <span><%= post.title %> </span>
        <span class="article-list__date"> <%= post.createdAt %> </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <% }) %>

  </ul>

I am trying to send data from main.js to index.ejs file but could not succeed.

Are you sure it const data = await Post.find(); returns data?console.log(data) to check it.Your route patha is emapty string. it shlid be something like /.

most likely you didn't mount the router in your app.js, include that code

Adding to the comments before, you are also missing a slash in the route. A basic route needs written as router.get('/', ....).
